# Merge the Space and Disk Usage tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/space) tag seems dubious at best, given it's current tag wiki:

> A space is a spot that is occupied or not occupied by something.

However the usage of the tag makes it pretty clearly a synonym of the clearer (and more common) [disk-usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/disk-usage) tag; should these two be merged and synonymized? I think [disk-usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/disk-usage) is clearly the preferable "master" tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After discussing this in chat, and thinking about it, I just did it.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)